# What is the purpose of using double underscore ( __ ) before the start and after the end of an file name in c?

Tags: android, c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, android-source

I'm studying the android kernel as a beginner. I can read the messages thrown from the macro `ERROR()` inside the function `main()` at `system/core/init/init.c` using `dmesg` command through adb. I observed that after calling the function `open_devnull_stdio()` inside `main()`, `dmesg` no longer displays the messages thrown by `ERROR()`.

To find the reason, I started digging into the declaration of `open_devnull_stdio()` inside `system/core/init/util.c` and I found this line I can't understand

> `static const char *name = "/dev/__null__"`;

Actually there was no file named `__null__` inside `/dev/` in the device, but there was a file named `null` and I was able to grab it using `adb pull` and it was a 0 byte (empty) file.

So why is a file name wrapped with double underscore (__) ?

Here is the link for the [util.c](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p4f2ryyp9f6556d/util.c?dl=0)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you might want to look up /dev/null. It's a well known "file". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device

Comment: The null device is quite a special thing. Can you give more examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special purpose of using double underscore before the start, after the end or both in C. From the point of view of C the file name is just a string, the operating system is free to interpret in whatever way it chooses. From the point of view of Linux, the same applies. Underscores in file names are just characters. They are not treated differently from the letters `b` and `t`.

If I guessed right and I'm reading [the same file as you](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.4_r1/init/util.c#378) (it might be a good idea to link to the source code you're reading) then it should be pretty obvious what the code does on the lines after the one you mentioned. The next lines are:

```
if (mknod(name, S_IFCHR | 0600, (1 << 8) | 3) == 0) {
    fd = open(name, O_RDWR);
    unlink(name);
```

Which creates the null device which is then opened and immediately deleted again.

I suspect this is done so that programs can run without access to the root filesystem and still be able to open the equivalent of `/dev/null`.

Comment: Thank you @Art. Yeah the both functions are the same. And I attached the file I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer but I have an idea:

The following page shows an "strace" output where `/dev/__null__` is used:

https://gist.github.com/tetsu-koba/1522515

Under Linux device files have a 33-bit (?) number which identifies the device. (At least under old Linux versions) you could delete some file in `/dev` and you could restore it or even create it in another directory (!) when you know the 33-bit number! (So you can delete the device `/dev/sda2` and create the device (not file!) `/home/myuser/sda2` instead.)

The trace in the link above shows the following three lines:

```
mknod("/dev/__null__", S_IFCHR|0600, makedev(1, 3)) = 0
open("/dev/__null__", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
unlink("/dev/__null__") = 0
```

These lines will create the device file `/dev/__null__` (with the 33-bit number identifying `/dev/null`). Then it opens that file and then it removes the file again.

Maybe this is done because the tool shall be able to run both on Linux installations where the device file "/dev/null" is present (in this case the file should not be overwritten) and on installations where that file is missing (in this case a replacement file must be created using the known 33-bit number).

Answer (score -1):

As other people have pointed out this just tells it's the "null device", not a regular file called "null". `null` is supposed to act like an information sink, not like a normal file where you dump your data to. Hope this helps.